# Document Library - filter

Tags: web-part, document, library, metadata-navigation, classic-experience

[image]Good morning,

Is it possible to apply Key Filter tree to a Document Library inside a WEBPART (not COLUMN HEADER FILTER)?

When I add the document library as a webpart I only see the webpart but not the METADATA NAVIGATION on the left side.

I want to include it in my Master page's webpart.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are working with pages and inserting your list as a web part then Metadata based filtering will not appear by default.
But you have several other options to mimic this behavior. you can have a look on the **"Filters"** web parts

There is a good reference available by [MSDN -Connect a Filter Web Part to a List View Web Part](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/connect-a-filter-web-part-to-a-list-view-web-part-on-a-classic-page-4f3f6c10-0a1b-479d-8b4d-c4f1bf49bb3f)

:[image]

Hope this helps!